# как сверстать картинку используя только HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

нужно сверстать картинку 1000х1000 px  используя только HTML/CSS. SVG и JavaScript использовать нельзя.
как это сделать?

Comment: Всмысле сверстать картинку? Если просто вставить картинку в текст и стилизовать - ок, для остального как минимум канвас надо будет

Comment: Сверстать картинку — это как сверстать БД :D

Comment: еще как вариант можно попробовать создать svg через css при помощи shape, но это немного ...странно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать таблицу, где каждая клетка будет "пикселем" и будет иметь определенный цвет. Графический редактор GIMP имеет возможность экспорта изображения в HTML-таблицу. Правда, в таком случае изображение 1000x1000px будет занимать много места и не факт, что браузер такое успешно загрузит.

Comment: А вы знаете толк в извращениях)

Answer (score 2):

Найдите работы, например, Дайаны Смит, и подсмотрите исходный код:

https://github.com/cyanharlow/purecss-gaze

https://diana-adrianne.com/